# Partial Match in a Grammar

Tags: raku

I have a simple grammar, and I am using it to parse some text. The text is user inputted, but my program guarantees that it stars with a match to the grammar. (ie, if my grammar matched only `a`, the text might be `abc` or `a` or `a_`.) However, when I use the `.parse` method on my grammar, it fails on any non-exact match. How can I perform a partial match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Raku, `Grammar.parse` has to match the whole string. This is what causes it to fail if your grammar would only match `a` in the string `abc`. To allow matching only part of the input string, you can use [`Grammar.subparse`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/subparse) instead.

```
grammar Foo {
    token TOP { 'a' }
}

my $string = 'abc';

say Foo.parse($string);    # Nil
say Foo.subparse($string); # ｢a｣
```

The input string will need to start with the potential `Match`. Otherwise, you will get a failed match.

```
say Foo.subparse('cbacb'); # #<failed match>
```

You can work around this using a [Capture marker](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex_%3C(_)%3E-Capture_markers:_%3C(_)%3E).

```
grammar Bar {
    token TOP {
        <-[a]>*   # Match 0 or more characters that are *not* a
        <( 'a'    # Start the match, and match a single 'a'
    }
}

say Bar.parse('a');        # ｢a｣
say Bar.subparse('a');     # ｢a｣
say Bar.parse('abc');      # Nil
say Bar.subparse('abc');   # ｢a｣
say Bar.parse('cbabc');    # Nil
say Bar.subparse('cbabc'); # ｢a｣
```

This works because `<-[a]>*`, a character class that includes any character *except* the letter `a`, will consume all the characters before a potential `a`. However, the Capture marker will cause these to be dropped from the eventual `Match` object, leaving you with just the `a` you wanted to match.

Comment: Will `.subparse` only match at the start, or match anywhere in the string?

Comment: Only at the start. I've updated my answer to reflect this more accurately, and present a potential workaround for that particular scenario.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

```
grammar foo { token TOP { a* } } 

# Partial match anchored at start of string:
say .subparse: 'abcaa' given foo; # ｢a｣ 

# Partial match anchored to end of string:
say 'abcaa' ~~ / <.foo::TOP> $ /; #  ｢aa｣

# Longest partial match, no anchoring:
say ('abcaaabcaabc' ~~ m:g/ <.foo::TOP> /).max(*.chars); #  ｢aaa｣
```

## Vocabulary

There are traditionally two takes on the general notion of text "matching":

- "Parsing"
- "Regexes"

Raku:

- Provides a unified text pattern language and engine that do both jobs.
- Makes it easy to stick to one perspective, or other, or blend them, or refactor between them, as suits an individual dev and/or individual use case.
- Takes "parsing" to mean more or less *a single match starting at the start of the input string* whereas "regexes" are much more flexible.

What you've written in your question and your first comment on Tyil's answer reflects the inherent ambiguity of the topic. I'll provide two answers rather than one to try help you and/or other readers to be clearer about Raku's use of vocabulary, and your options functionality wise.

## **Limited** "partial matching" via `.parse` et al

You began with:

> Partial match in a **grammar** ... I have a simple **grammar** ... my program **guarantees that it starts** with a match to the **grammar**

With that in mind, here's your question:

> How can I perform a *partial match*?

The phrases "guarantees that it starts" and "partial match" are ambiguous.

One take is that you want what I'll call a "prefix" match, matching one or more characters anchored from the start of the string, and not merely any sub-string starting and ending anywhere in the input string.

This nicely fits with "parsing", or at least Raku's use of the word in its grammar methods.

**All** the built in `Grammar` methods with `parse` in their name insert an anchor to the start of the string in whatever grammar rule they use to start the parsing process. *You cannot remove that anchor.* This reflects the choice of vocabulary; "parse" is taken to mean matching *from the start* no matter what else happens.

The parse method for this "prefix" scenario is `.subparse`:

```
grammar foo { token TOP { a* } } 

# Partial match anchored at start of string:
say .subparse: 'abcaa' given foo; # ｢a｣
```

See also:

- [Search of SO for "[raku] subparse"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+subparse).
- [raku doc for `.subparse`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/subparse).

---

But perhaps "guarantees that it starts" and "partial match" did *not* mean that you wanted anchoring at the start. Your comment on Tyil's answer highlights this ambiguity:

> Will `.subparse` only match at the start, or match anywhere in the string?

Tyil provides a workaround. You *can* do what Tyil shows, but it'll only match if the very first `a` encountered in the input string is the one that's at the start of the sub-string you want your "parse" to match.

If instead the first `a` was a false positive, and there was a *second* or a subsequent `a` you wanted the "parse" match to start at, then, at least in the Raku world, it's helpful to call that "regexing" rather than "parsing" and to use "regex" matching via [the `~~` smartmatch operator](https://docs.raku.org/routine/%7E%7E).

## **Un**limited "partial matching" via `~~`

Raku lets you do *unlimited* partial matching if you use its `~~` construct with a regex.

For example, you could write:

```
# End of match at end of string:
                          ↓
say 'abcaa' ~~ token { a* $ } #  ｢aa｣
```

`~~` with a regex tells Raku to:

- Try match starting at the first character position in the string on the LHS;
- If that fails, step forward one character, and try again, with the new position in the input string treated as a fresh starting point;
- Repeat that until either matching once, or failing to find any match in the entire string.

Here I've left the start position of the match unspecified (which `~~` takes to mean it can be anywhere in the string) and anchored the end of the pattern to the end of the input string. So it successfully matches the `aa` at the end of the string.

This anchoring freedom illustrates just one of the many ways that `~~` smart matching provides much greater matching flexibility than using the `parse` methods.

---

If you have an existing grammar you can still use that:

```
grammar foo { token TOP { a* } } 

# Anchor matching to end of string:
                             ↓
say 'abcaa' ~~ / <.foo::TOP> $ /; #  ｢aa｣
```

You have to name both the grammar and the rule within it you wish to invoke and put them inside `<...>`. And you need to insert a `.` to avoid a correspondingly named sub-capture, presuming you don't want that.

---

Here's another example:

```
# Longest partial match, no anchoring:
say ('abcaaabcaabc' ~~ m:g/ <.foo::TOP> /).max(*.chars); #  ｢aaa｣
```

"Parsing" in Raku always starts at the beginning of an input string *and results in either no match or ***one*** match*.

In contrast, a "regex" can match arbitrary fragments, and can match *any number* of fragments. (You can even match overlapping fragments.)

In my last example I used `:g`, which is short for `:global`, which is a well known feature among traditional regex engines. `:g` matches as many times as a match is found in the input string (but not overlapping).

The match operation then returns either `Nil` (no matches at all) or a *list* of match objects (one or more). I've applied a `.max(*.chars)` to yield the longest match (the first if there are multiple longest sub-strings).